# Would an expression tree work here?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I have the below method that I currently use to get the DB length of certain string fields (each property has an attribute called MetaDataFieldAttribute). It seems to work nicely however it's very 'stringly' typed with the property name.

```
     public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ...
            obj.PropertyName = str.TrimIfRequired(obj, "PropertyName");
        }

        public static string TrimIfRequired(this string str, object obj, string property)
        {
            var pi = obj.GetType().GetProperty(property);
            var attribute = pi.GetCustomAttributes<MetaDataFieldAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (attribute == null) return str;

            int length = attribute.Precision;
            return str.Length > length ? str.Substring(0, length) : str;
        }
```

I have a fairly basic understanding of expression trees, and my initial thought is that I could make the object/parameter of the method strongly typed rather than just passing through the string. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can use Expressions here just to get strong typing for property names, so instead of writing property name as string, you can use expression with property access, and then code will get MemberInfo item for specific property from expression and will get attribute from here. So if you change propertyName in the future, this part won't compile as it will be strong typed.

here is working sample on .NetFiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/qYOfhE

And here is the code itself:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var str = "TestTestTest";

        var propertyName = str.TrimIfRequired<Customer>((c) => c.FirstName);
        var propertyNameValue = str.TrimIfRequired<Customer>((c) => c.Age);
        Console.WriteLine(propertyName);
        Console.WriteLine(propertyNameValue);
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string TrimIfRequired<T>(this string str, Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
    {
        var me = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (me == null && expr.Body is UnaryExpression)
        {
            me = ((UnaryExpression) expr.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
        }

        if (me == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid expression. It should be MemberExpression");
        }

        var pi = me.Member;
        var attribute = pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetaDataFieldAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as MetaDataFieldAttribute;
        if (attribute == null) return str;

        int length = attribute.Precision;
        return str.Length > length ? str.Substring(0, length) : str;
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    [MetaDataField(Precision = 6)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MetaDataField(Precision = 2)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}


public class MetaDataFieldAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Precision { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This will fail for value type parameters, as they will be a convert to object of the member access (expr.Body will be UnaryExpression). Either make the method generic with 2 type parameters (e.g TrimIfRequired<T, TProp>(this string str, Expression<Func<T, TProp>> propertyAccess), or actually I would introduce a 'capture' class inbetween, so you dont have to type the property type), or handle the wrapping with UnaryExpression too!

Comment: @MBoros yeah, you are totally right. I went with simple solution and updated my answer to count `UnaryExpression` as we don't do actual property access and boxing isn't a problem here, but adding new `TProp` might complicate usage a bit

Answer (score 0):

It would work, but only if inside `Main` the 'obj' variable had a well-known type. `object` is not enough, because any expression trees given `object` as the referred type will simply not see any actual members. But since you already assign to the `PropertyName`, then it seems you have that variable typed.

Your `TrimIfRequired` would also need to be changed, i.e. to:

```
public static string TrimIfRequired<T>(this string str, T obj, Expression<Func<T,object>> propexpr)
```

used like this:

```
obj.PropertyName = str.TrimIfRequired(obj, o => o.PropertyName);
```

or

```
public static string TrimIfRequired<T>(this string str, Expression<Func<T,object>> propexpr)
```

used like this (*without* object instance, but with type explicitely stated)

```
obj.PropertyName = str.TrimIfRequired<MyType>(o => PropertyName);
```

First one is nice, since you just give the `obj` and C# automatically picks T for that and lambda also can use it immediatelly. However, you need to have the `obj` variable. Second example is useful when you know the concrete type, but don't have any variable or instance to pass. That's rare however.

In both cases, you get an `Expression<Func<T,..>>` that you need to analyze. Most often, you will get MemberExpression (property, field) and from it you will need to extract the property name. But keep in mind that the user can write anything in the lambda - for the compiler, `o => { foreach(..) {..}; return 1;}` is just as good as `o => o.PropertyName`, so you should detect if correct expression was passed and provide at least some minimal developerror handling.

BTW1. Instead of Func you may also use Action, but I think they are odd in usage in this context.

However, since you effectively want to trim an object's property length to some restriction defined on that property, I think that following tools would be more useful or ergonomic:

1) helper that immediately writes the value (get the propertyinfo as with any other expression, then use the fact the helper was called on `this obj` and use it to call `PropertyInfo.SetValue`)

```
obj.TrimIfRequired(o => o.PropertyName);
```

2) helper that walks over properties and applies all restrictions to all properties (we know the object's runtime Type, we can scan its Properties, get their Attributes, we know exactly what needs trimming)

```
obj.TrimAllIfRequired();
```